# Apticron should only send mails with security/ critical updates

Tags: security, configuration, updates

I have been using apticron for a while and it works finde but i get every day emails with new updates but i'm only interested in the security/ critical updates. Does anyone know a possibility that I only get an email when a security update is available. I looked in /etc/apticron/apticron.conf but there is no security option.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update.
At the apticron.conf is not really a point to configure the security information.

But i use the following option:

```sh
 13 # Set DIFF_ONLY to "1" to only output the difference of the current run
 14 # compared to the last run (ie. only new upgrades since the last run). If there
 15 # are no differences, no output/email will be generated. By default, apticron
 16 # will output everything that needs to be upgraded.
 17 #
 18 # DIFF_ONLY="1"
 19 #
 20 DIFF_ONLY="1"
```

and

```sh
 73 # Set NOTIFY_HOLDS="0" if you don't want to be notified about new versions of
 74 # packages on hold in your system. The default behavior is downloading and
 75 # listing them as any other package.
 76 #
 77 # NOTIFY_HOLDS="0"
 78 #
 79 NOTIFY_HOLDS="0"
```

This is not the solution i want but it is ok.

If anyone has a better option please let me know. :)